# Excel bracket using VBA not working?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, visual-studio

Making an autograde of sorts for an excel bracket with the guesses of each bracket in the ranges marked. Still clearly work in progress, finally have it running through, but the loop isn't working, it's returning pointSum of 0. Trying to sum += 10 when points is true.

```
Sub foo()
Dim Player(1 To 35) As String
    Player(1) = Range("M2")
    Player(2) = Range("M4")
    Player(3) = Range("M10")
    Player(4) = Range("M12")
    Player(5) = Range("M22")
    Player(6) = Range("M24")
    Player(7) = Range("M32")
    Player(8) = Range("M34")

    Player(9) = Range("L1")
    Player(10) = Range("L3")
    Player(11) = Range("L5")
    Player(12) = Range("L7")

    Player(13) = Range("L9")
    Player(14) = Range("L11")
    Player(15) = Range("L13")
    Player(16) = Range("L15")
    Player(17) = Range("L20")
    Player(18) = Range("L22")
    Player(19) = Range("L24")
    Player(20) = Range("L26")
    Player(21) = Range("L28")
    Player(22) = Range("L30")
    Player(23) = Range("L32")
    Player(24) = Range("L34")

    Player(25) = Range("K2")
    Player(26) = Range("K6")
    Player(27) = Range("K10")
    Player(28) = Range("K14")
    Player(29) = Range("K21")
    Player(30) = Range("K25")
    Player(31) = Range("K29")
    Player(32) = Range("J4")

    Player(33) = Range("J12")
    Player(34) = Range("J23")
    Player(35) = Range("J31")

Dim Winner(1 To 18) As String

    Winner(1) = "Mohler"
    Winner(2) = "Scotter"
    Winner(3) = "DKGAY"
    Winner(4) = "Lassie"

    Winner(5) = "Mohler"
    Winner(6) = "Gunnar"
    Winner(7) = "Gord'n"
    Winner(8) = "Hellmers"
    Winner(9) = "Evan Brown"
    Winner(10) = "Jerru"
    Winner(11) = "Case"
    Winner(12) = "Lassie"

    Winner(13) = "Mohler"
    Winner(14) = ""
    Winner(15) = ""
    Winner(16) = "Mohler"
    Winner(17) = "Mohler"
    Winner(18) = ""

Dim Guess(1 To 18) As String


    Guess(1) = Player(10)
    Guess(2) = Player(14)
    Guess(3) = Player(18)
    Guess(4) = Player(23)

    Guess(5) = Player(25)
    Guess(6) = Player(26)
    Guess(7) = Player(27)
    Guess(8) = Player(28)
    Guess(9) = Player(29)
    Guess(10) = Player(30)
    Guess(11) = Player(31)
    Guess(12) = Player(32)

    Guess(13) = ""
    Guess(14) = ""
    Guess(15) = ""
    Guess(16) = ""
    Guess(17) = ""
    Guess(18) = ""

Dim points(1 To 18) As Boolean
    points(1) = False
    points(2) = False
    points(3) = False
    points(4) = False
    points(5) = False
    points(6) = False
    points(7) = False
    points(8) = False
    points(9) = False
    points(10) = False
    points(11) = False
    points(12) = False

    points(13) = False
    points(14) = False
    points(15) = False
    points(16) = False
    points(17) = False
    points(18) = False


Dim pointSum As Double
    pointSum = 0

Dim pointValue(1 To 6) As Double
    pointValue(1) = 10
    pointValue(2) = 20
    pointValue(3) = 30
    pointValue(4) = 40
    pointValue(5) = 50
    pointValue(6) = 60

For i = 1 To 12 Step 1
    If Guess(i) = Winner(i) Then
        points(i) = True And pointSum = pointSum + 10
    Else
        points(i) = False
    End If
Next

Range("O1") = pointSum
MsgBox "Done!"   
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> For i = 1 To 12 Step 1
>     If Guess(i) = Winner(i) Then
>         points(i) = True And pointSum = pointSum + 10
>     Else
>         points(i) = False
>     End If
> Next
> ```

Ok, several things.

```
Step 1
```

That's the default; the `Step` part of the `For` loop definition is usually only included when its value is different than `1`. But that won't cause any problems.

```
points(i) = True And pointSum = pointSum + 10
```

If I understand your question correctly...

> *the loop isn't working, it's returning pointSum of 0. Trying to sum += 10 when points is true.*

You're not assigning `pointSum` anywhere. The above line of code is interpreted as follows:

```
points(i) = (True And (pointSum = pointSum + 10))
```

In other words:

```
points(i) = (True And False)
```

In other words:

```
points(i) = False
```

When you make an *assignment*, the variable being *assigned to* goes on the left side of the *assignment* operator (`=`):

```
foo = 42 'assigns value 42 to foo
```

The confusion seems to be that in VBA, the *comparison* operator is *also* a `=` token:

```
If foo = 42 Then 'true when the value of foo is 42
```

---

To increment `pointSum` by `10` when `points(i)` is `True`, you can do this:

```
If points(i) = True Then pointSum = pointSum + 10
```

Which can be simplified to:

```
If points(i) Then pointSum = pointSum + 10
```

Because the `(boolean expression)` in `If (boolean expression) Then` doesn't need to be compared to `True` or `False` when you're already working with a `Boolean` variable.

Hope it helps!